# create custom url in GET method form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="get" id='searchform' action="http://example.com/search">
<select name="a[]" multipile>
    <option value="car volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
<select>
</form>
<select name="b[]" multipile>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
<select>
<input type="number" name="range[]" min="1" max="5">
<button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

I want this URL:

```
http://example.com/search?a=car+volvo+OR+saab&b=opel+audi&range=1..5
```

I could send form by post to server and and then  create new url with my custom url (with php) and then redirect it to new page (with my custom url).

But can I do it with only HTML (or javascript?) do your recomment it?)

Comment: note: it should be `action="http://example.com/search"` instead of `method="http://example.com/search"`

Comment: @Kaddath. thanks. It was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jQuery [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

```
var formData = $("#searchform").serialize():
var url = "http://myurl?"+formData;
```

But in order to get what you're trying to create, you'll need to rename your inputs as right now they are stored as input arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to submit your form data using a static html page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#html_form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type : "post",
   url : "test2.php",
   data : $(this).serialize(),
   encode : true
  }).done(function(data){
   console.log(data);
  });
 });
});
```

This step is also described in detail [here](http://lookingforawebsitedesigner.online/how-to-submit-a-form-using-html-jquery/).